# MongoDb query to find specific object in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

i have an array of object **player_of_day** inwhich there is again array of user-Ids i.e. **nominate_by** I want to find an object having maximum count.
Something like-
an object from **player_of_day** whose count is maximum

```
"player_of_day" : [
        {
            "nominate_by" : [
                ObjectId("58994bca4187b412aec50c94"),
                ObjectId("58994a124187b412aec50c91"),
                ObjectId("589955d54187b412aec50c99")
            ],
            "nominate_to" : ObjectId("58994b374187b412aec50c93"),
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "nominate_by" : [
                ObjectId("58994c254187b412aec50c95"),
                ObjectId("58994ad04187b412aec50c92")
            ],
            "nominate_to" : ObjectId("58994a124187b412aec50c91"),
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "nominate_by" : [
                ObjectId("58994b374187b412aec50c93")
            ],
            "nominate_to" : ObjectId("58994c254187b412aec50c95"),
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
```

Comment: what result you expecting, can you show some sample

Comment: I just want a record from player_of_day whose count is maximum

Comment: For eg:-in above eg,max count is 3 so,in result I want:-       "nominate_by" : [
                ObjectId("58994bca4187b412aec50c94"),
                ObjectId("58994a124187b412aec50c91"),
                ObjectId("589955d54187b412aec50c99")
            ],
            "nominate_to" : ObjectId("58994b374187b412aec50c93"),
            "count" : 3

Comment: if you have an array of objects, you can loop it checking the max value

Comment: db.match.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$player_of_day"},{"$sort":{count:-1}}, {"$limit":1}]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
db.match.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$player_of_day"},{"$sort":{'player_of_day.count':-1}},{"$limit":1}]);
```

Comment: @Rama-tx for your help....can I get only **"nominate_to"** as output whose count is maximum in that record

Comment: $project will help on this db.match.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$player_of_day"},{"$sort":{'player_of_day.count':-1}},{"$limit":1},{"$project":{"player_of_day.nominate_to":1}}]);

Comment: i have used this-db.matches.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$player_of_day"},{"$sort":{'player_of_day.count':-1}},{"$limit":1},{‌​"$project":{"player_‌​of_day.nominate_to":‌​1}}]);

Comment: but giving me error and Iam not able to find out-2017-02-15T15:43:03.602+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:102

Comment: are you able to run query without $project?

Comment: you have to check your mongo version, i think it is not supporting

Comment: I have 3.2.10 mongo version

Comment: No,its not working.I have used - db.matches.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$player_of_day"},{"$sort":{'player_of_day.count':-1}},{"$limit":1},{‌​"$project":{"player_‌​of_day.nominate_to":‌​1}}]);
But it giving me error-2017-02-15T17:17:03.654+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:102